# Why attempt to scan in the name produces segmentation fault?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I am new to programming. I typed this simple code and I keep getting this error message. Does anyone know the reason why the compiler stops working? I have checked the compiler settings and clicked auto detect. It still does not work though.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Btw I am new to programming so break it down if explaining something.

```
#include <sdtio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int name;
    printf("What is your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", name);

    printf("Your name is %s", name);    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Don't post images of text.  Copy and paste it here.

Comment: The compiler doesn't stop working. It's your program that crashes when run.

Comment: Use **%d** for type **int** instead **%s**

Comment: Please do not post code as image, it does not allow to use the code by someone else to try and reproduce the problem, copy paste the text form, this time I've done it for you, but please read the link I mentioned in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, you're using wrong argument type for a particular format specifier (or we can say, vice-versa). `%s` expects a pointer to `char` array as argument, not an `int`. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to use a `char` array to input a *string*, something like

```
#define SIZE 32
char name[SIZE] = {0};
```

and then using `%s` format specifier will be correct. Something like

```
scanf("%31s", name);  //32-1, reserve one for null-terminator
```

will do the job.

Comment: `scanf` `%s` is a buffer overflow waiting to happen. In some sense, `%s` is never correct.

Comment: @melpomene unless you don;t let it happen. Updated. :)

Comment: our answers are pretty much the same.. so deleted it. nice answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` format specifier expects a pointer to a `char` (which points to an array of `char`), but `name` is an `int`.

Change `name` to a character array.

```
char name[100];
```